# Verify p2p node

Tags: c#, encryption, networking, encryption-asymmetric

Hey guys, I have been working on a p2p namespace for some of my programs.  I created a system to encrypt/decrypt the packets send/received with the class.  I was using the basic public private key system: 1) encrypt the data with Symmetric encryption 2) encrypt the symmetric key with RSA.  Then do the opposite when you decrypted..

I was wondering though, how would you verify if the packet was coming from where it said it was.  I was going to use a basic certificate system (where you encrypt with your private RSA key, then they decrypt it with your public key), but I don't know how to do this with C#.  I am using the RSACryptoServiceProvider class.

Does anyone know how do this?
Thanks,
Max

Comment: Hm, that happens when you only have one other question open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard protocol for sending packets securely is SSL/TLS. The RFCs for [TLS](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) and [DTLS](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347.txt) (and [a fix for a recent flaw](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc5746.txt)) are the way to go. They should also be considered a resource for those learning and looking for ideas.

It sounds like you're a looking for a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). A very efficient set of crypto primitives that perform both encryption and MACing at the same time are the [AEAD](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5116.txt) ciphers, see for example [CCM](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38C/SP800-38C_updated-July20_2007.pdf) and [GCM](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf) block cipher modes.

I do not believe .NET supports any AEAD ciphers. You can also use the slower but perfectly adequate [HMAC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt) algorithm which is supported in .NET, or you can use the [bouncycastle C# library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) which does support AEAD ciphers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not much of a cryptographer, could you "dumb it down" a bit for me ;)

I need a way for one computer to know that a packet is from the sender it says it is.  A MAC wouldn't work (I was able to understand that for the most part), I am already sending md5 hashes over.
Thanks, 
Max

Comment: All the more reason to use a canned solution like SSL. It is too hard to dumb down, I think. It requires some study before being understood. Perhaps someone else can do better.

Comment: I'm sorry I completely forgot about this question, but still would like an anwser.  As I was reading through the definition of a MAC, I realized that isn't what I need.  I need a certificate, that I can generate off of a predefined RSA key (using the previously mentioned RSACryptoServiceProvider class)